# Java equivilant to pythons / haskells map() function with multiprocessing/multithreading?

Tags: java, python, multithreading, multiprocessing

I know there have been questions which are similar to mine. However, they seem very outdated (assuming JDK 7, etc.) 
So, I've been programming python for a while and had to learn Java for university.
I know that [there is a feature in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28463266/8970885), where you can use a pool of Threads/Processes for mapping a list of values to a function.

```
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool 
pool = ThreadPool(4) 
results = pool.map(my_function, my_array)
```

I have to use the function on a large set of files and I have to use Java (10) and I want to use multiprocessing. 
My question is: Does Java have such a feature? If so, whats the best practice to use it properly?

Comment: @rocksportrocker the answer was valid at the time it was made, now 5 years later, there are other possibilities , like stream().parallel()...

Comment: You could use paralell streams, perhaps (depending on the task, whether it is interfering etc.) - but be careful: you said you wanted to process a lot of files. Paralellizing disk access is going to make performance worse, not better!

Comment: @GPI - that doesn't mean that the question is not a duplicate. It means that if you want to answer it, you should go and add an answer there, rather than have duplicate questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use [`parallelStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/parallelism.html), for example, convert integer list to string list:

```
List<Integer> list = List.of(1, 2);

List<String> strings =
        list.parallelStream()
                .map(integer -> String.valueOf(integer)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```